# How to check if Strings all characters in a specific unicode range?

Tags: c#

Hi for example i have a `String` in sinhala unicode

```
 String variable = "සහ"; - Correct String
 String variable = "XසහS"; - Incorrect String
```

I want to validate if **ALL the characters** string is in the specific unicode range which belongs to that specific language.

Any idea of achiving this ?

Comment: @Patrick: Not correct. `var` is a *contextual* keyword. Because of that, `var` is still valid as a variable name. Otherwise, when `var` was introduced to the language, it might have broken code.

Comment: Just a note to say that checking whether all characters in a string fall within a specified Unicode block range is not the same as determining whether the string is well-formed. The dependent vowels in sinhala need to follow a consonant character, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
static bool Validate(string s, char max, char min)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        if (s[i] > max || s[i] < min)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is determining `min` and `max`. And then there's the other problem of it not necessarily being a *single* range.

Answer (score 0):

Ghosts's function in a single line:

```
static bool Validate(string s, char max, char min) {
    return s.All(c => min <= c && c <= max);
}
```

Comment: First, your answer should just be a comment or edit of the original. If you're going to do it in a single line, you really should say `!s.Any(c => c > max || c < min)` or `s.All(c => min <= c && c <= max)`. You don't want to know the *count* of the number of characters outside the range, you want to know if there are *any* characters outside the range or if *all* of the characters are inside the range. But, this problem is [not that simple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773531/c-sharp-how-to-check-if-strings-all-characters-in-a-specific-unicode-range/17773577#comment25922535_17773577).

Comment: You're right about using `Any()` or `All()`, I've updated the answer. Also, see http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0D80.pdf - Sinhalese script was added to the Unicode Standard in September 1999 with the release of version 3.0.
The Unicode block for Sinhala is U+0D80–U+0DFF. Grey areas indicate non-assigned code points. (via Wikipedia)